Understand console messages with AI
I read this article about the new Gemini features that allows to understand console messages through AI, but I don't have the option "Understand console messages with AI" in my Settings.
I'm in Italy, is it a feature available in my country or is it available in US only?
Thank you

See the requirements.

I saw it, but it just says "Are located in one of the supported regions and are at least 18 years old."
Where can I see the supported regions?
